# Docusign The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified

Tags: sdk, docusignapi

Last week I make some test in the demo environment and when try to make some test a get this message "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified." And if I go to the docusign developer site, the integration keys have a color gray in the status.

How I cant resolve this?

Thanks,
Ev

Comment: can you say which URL you call when you get the error?

Comment: can you share a screenshot of your "gray" IK

Comment: can you create a new IK?

Comment: Hi,  Thanks, I resolved the error. Im connected to an vpn that blocks the request.

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem were that I was connected to a VPN that was blocking the request to docusign.
Thanks,
EV

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue is resolved:
The IK may have been blocked (grayed out) because of a connection issue. User reported that the VPN was blocking their requests.
This can also occur when trying to connect to the wrong URL (production instead of developer sandbox).